# How to find My home directory is hosted and technology of storage system where my home directory is hosted

Tags: unix, filesystems, nfs

I want to know two things
1. Unix command or how to find where my home directory is hosted.
2. And technology of storage system where my home directory is hosted.

Also please suggest a good source to know how NFS filesystem works.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you want to know. As a start, try

```
% df ~
Filesystem   512-blocks       Used Available Capacity iused               ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s1 1953595632 1254028928 689716648    65% 6420347 9223372036848355460    0%   /
```

The first and last items might be helpful. See also the [Question and Answer about "How to get the complete and exact list of mounted filesystems in Linux?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24182/how-to-get-the-complete-and-exact-list-of-mounted-filesystems-in-linux)